# Regex to validate email addresses with multiple rules defined

Tags: regex

Help! little to no experience with regex and tasked with complicated rules.

I have the below requirements that I need to include in regex for matching email address format.

format:
recipientname@domain.top

Recipient name:

1. cannot begin or end with one of the following characters and they cannot appear consecutively: !_#-{}~*'&$%^+=`|.?
2. with the exception of the special characters in #1, can only contain a-z, A-Z, or 0-9
3. cannot contain any of the following characters: "<>()@[]:;,
4. cannot exceed 64 characters in length

domain:

1. Can only contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, . or -
2. cannot exceed 253 characters in length

I feel like this can be done a lot easier but this is where I've gotten so far with no experience. I cannot figure out how to put the character limit for the recipient name and #1 for the consecutive special characters rule seems to be applying to the whole string instead of just the recipient name.

^(([^!*#-{}~*'&$%^+=`|\\.?\/ "<>()@\[\]:;,])(?!.*[!_#\-{}~*'&$%^+=`|\.?]{2})[^ "<>()@[]:;,][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^!*#-{}~*'&$%^+=`|\.?/ "<>()@[]:;,])@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,253}..*)$

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9]{2})(?=[A-Za-z0-9])([\w!#$%&'*+.=?^\`{|}~\-]{1,64})@([A-Za-z0-9.-]{3,253})$
```

> `^` : start of line or string
>
> `(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9]{2})` : characters that aren't letters or numbers may not appear consecutively
>
> `(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` : has to start with letter or digit
>
> `` ([\w!#$%&'*+.=?^`{|}~\-]{1,64}) `` : 1 to 64 characters from the list
>
> `@` : no email without the ampersant
>
> `([A-Za-z0-9.-]{3,253})` : 3 to 253 letter or digits or dash or dot
>
> `$` : end of line or string